# How does time travelling work in attack on titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the Manga,

> Its shown that Eren was the one who asked his father to eat the former founding titan and give the power to Eren. How does it work ?What all can Eren do under time travelling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one can time travel forward or backwards in time. At least, not yet.

When Eren and Zeke were watching Grisha’s memories, they noticed that Grisha didn’t want to kill the Reiss family. Eren inherited the Attack titan from Grisha, and so he was able to transfer future memories to Grisha because every titan shifter is connected to Paths, and it’s because Grisha and Eren have the same titan that he is able to send them. He shows Grisha those memories and is able to speak to him, essentially manipulating him to do the dirty work of killing the Reiss family.

However, I do have a theory that time travel is possible. When Eren wakes up from his dream in the first chapter, he tell Mikasa that her hair became longer. He is crying but never tells why he is. I believe that when Eren was able to fully use the founding titan, he either sent his memories to past Eren (which is unlikely because he doesn’t have the Attack titan, unless Eren was able to send them to past Eren because he is an Eldian), or he was reborn into a new timeline where he wakes up from dreaming all of his memories, sort of like Bunny Girl Senpai, and redoes everything because he must have failed at something to make him restart. This explains why Eren says she has longer hair, Mikasa has short hair in the recent manga chapters.

Comment: mindblowing theory :O

Comment: yes and I even think that something similar happens with Falco as well. In the first episode of season 4 even he talks about using odm maneuver gears and killing titans. Maybe something  happens to him later on similar to what you told happens with Eren.